# Dynamically reposition dropdown menu in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I populate my drop down menu in IE, it doesn't re-center. This is what it should look like (which it does in chrome):

[image: correct]

However, this is what it is doing:

[image: incorrect]

There must be an easy way to reset the menu back to center and resize the box?

This is the function that populates the menu:

```
function PopResources()
{
    $('#resources').html("<option>loading..</option>");
    $.get("resources.php",
            {"param":"getresources"},
            function(returned_data)
            {
                //alert(returned_data);
                $('#resources').html(returned_data);
            });
}
```

Comment: Is this not just a CSS issue? Doe it look centered in IE before you populate it?

Comment: try this
#resources{margin-right:40px;}

Comment: I'm with Diodeus: you need to share some HTML and CSS for adequate context.

Comment: i'm just using <td align="center">, no CSS and it was centered before populating. I'm trying to avoid CSS, I'm new to web dev

Comment: You may be new to web dev, but that should be all the more reason to NOT avoid CSS, because css is a large part of web developement.

Comment: I'm looking for a cheap, easy alternative :P Is there not one? I'm doing web dev because we don't have a web developer. I want it working and displaying properly. Not too much into making it look nice.

Comment: We still need to see your HTML - post it on jsfiddle.net

Comment: html was unnecessary, see below answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know your particular case (without html and css), but sometimes these type of display issues can be resolved by turning off and then turning back on the `display` of the element at the end of the script (this usually works in the case of refresh issues as the browser is "forced" to recalculate the element).

For jquery something like this at the end of the script:

```
$("#resources").toggle().toggle();
```